# How to manipulate HTTP Headers in the WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#

I want to use proxy on web-browser control. But I faced a sophisticated problem. Web-browser sends extra parameters on HTTP that shows web-browser is working with proxy. These parameters are "VIA, HTTP_X_FORWARD, PROXY_ID" and My real IP would shown to remote webserver. Hence I need a solution to manipulate the parameters but I don't know a certain way how to do that.

What now I need to do for manipulating header parameters ?

Comment: [Say what now?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you using Visual Basic or C#?  The answer may depend on that.  If you can use either, you should specify that in the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it isn't your browser but rather the proxy that appends those headers to your requests. If you want to check what leaves your browser you could use a tool such as Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the traffic.

Comment: I also believe that. But I tested with 2 different software: proxifier and browser. and then find out some browsers are proxy-aware, it binds paramteres by itself.